# Skipping Months

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

My calendar is not rendering days for April because when I view April in the calendar it starts with March 29. So it pulls data for March.

My calendar view for April...

3/29 | 3/30 | 3/31 | 4/1 | 4/2

Since the month starts in March, I only get events for March. How do I fix this?

Comment: you might find another name makes people more inclined to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

I just update the start date/time passed to the events function with this code...

```
events: function(start, end, callback) {
var start = $j('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
```

GJ Don. Not many people pick up on the name.

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it